# Weird space in Windows %path% environment variable

Tags: java, windows, maven, path

Sorry; I want to show images but I can't upload them.

```
C:\Users\Kang Juho>echo %Path%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Wizvera\Delfino;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS
\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86
)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL S
erver\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\P
rogram Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer; ‪C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05
\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.2\bin;C:\Users
\Kang Juho\AppData\Local\Bandizip\7z;
```

Here you can see a space between "Platform Installer" and "C:\Program Files" (on the third-last line).

The weird thing is that I can see this space in the Windows Console, but if I copy it and paste it elsewhere, there is no space.

I checked, and there is no space in the path settings.

Because of this, I can't use maven and javac.

```
C:\Users\Kang Juho>mvn -version

Error: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory.
JAVA_HOME = "‪ C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05"
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

This is really weird, and I can't find solutions..

/////add

[a link] https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjIcB.jpg

here is the image url you can see a space in it;
i think this can might be a localization or text encoding problem

////solved

short style directory name works

Comment: What do you need an image of? Paths and the command line are text.

Comment: Your PATH has zero to do with JAVA_HOME. Perhaps you pasted the value from a web page instead of typing it and got a funky HTML-ish character in it? Redo your JAVA_HOME setting.

Comment: upload the image to [imgur.com](http://imgur.com/) and just throw the url in a comment, someone will edit your post and put the image in for you

Comment: Just copy and paste into Notepad to sanitize. Delete and re-type that particular portion. You'll be fine then.

Comment: Go into your windows environment variable settings and delete the space.  I'm not sure how your path variable is related to your JAVA_HOME variable, but it looks like there's a leading space there as well.

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: This is Windows Embedded 8.1 industry pro and i think the localization will be Korean Sorry but the comments doesn't help me they are out of the point of the problem  @HarryJohnston seems to notice the problem

Comment: I notice the problem too, that's why I suggested deleting that part entirely and re-typing it. Please see my answer.

Comment: @ADTC I saw your answer and that was what I already did for several times. the notepad thing is what I always do when I encouter text problems... but now solved thanks for commenting continuosly.

Comment: Hmm, OK good you got it solved, but I wonder if this is somehow due to the Korean localization using that weird *stroked `W`* character instead of the regular backslash.

Comment: @ADTC I think it is not haha... the real problem might be my tired  mental trying to solve it for 2 hours.... after some sleep and help the problem got solved thanks for help

Comment: @ADTC that W character is not problem i think. that is becaus of the default font of korean windows. Korean keyboards actually doesnt have backslash.. and that character means Won which is money currency like the doller mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a non-breaking space character (which gets converted to normal space in command prompt). Non-breaking space appears invisible in Unicode text (what is shown in Windows GUI), therefore it will appear as if there is no space at all.

Your best bet is to re-type the variable values by hand, thereby eliminating the original problem completely (you will be deleting away the invisible space character and you will not be typing it back in).

Since your Maven installation refers to `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, I suggest you delete this variable from the environment variable settings* and add it back.

Do not reuse the same value, but instead find the root (home) folder of your Java installation, then copy its full path. Use this copied path when adding the variable back. Also, do not do this in a command prompt window as it will not persist.

You can also refresh the `PATH` variable value similarly by selecting and deleting the text part with the problem and re-typing it correctly. Note that you do not need to delete the whole `PATH` variable.

```
// Select and delete:
Web Platform Installer; ‪C:\Program Files
// Re-type as:
Web Platform Installer;C:\Program Files
```

**Tip:** Use a software like [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/) to manage the environment variables more easily. Such software will have advanced tools like editing each path value separately and removing/correcting invalid paths.

* For *Windows 7*, right-click Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Advanced (tab) > Environment Variables.